# How to get the input and output names of .pb model converted from darknet

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, coreml, coremltools

I trained a model on darknet using the YOLOv3-SPP model. I need to be able to use this model in my iPhone app so I need to convert it to CoreML. I started by converting the .weights file to a .pb file. Now I am trying to convert it from TensorFlow to CoreML with `tfcoreml`. However I cannot seem to determine my input and output tensor names. I tried to use tensorboard to visualize the model and determine the inputs and outputs but since I am quite new to TensorFlow I can't figure out what to use. I am using this script to convert the model from TensorFlow to CoreML:

```
import tfcoreml
import os
import tensorflow as tf

frozen_model_file = os.path.abspath('frozen_darknet_yolov3_model.pb')
input_tensor_shapes = {"input/placeholder:0": [1, 32, 32, 9]}
# Output CoreML model path
coreml_model_file = './model.mlmodel'
output_tensor_names = ['output/prediction:0']
def convert():
    # Read the pb model
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_model_file, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    # Then, we import the graph_def into a new Graph
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    # Convert
    tfcoreml.convert(
        tf_model_path=frozen_model_file,
        mlmodel_path=coreml_model_file,
        input_name_shape_dict=input_tensor_shapes,
        output_feature_names=output_tensor_names)
convert()
```

This what my tensorboard looks like:

[image]

What should I set the `input_tensor_shapes` and `output_tensor_names` too so that I don't get an error saying that my TensorFlow graph does not contain a tensor with that name.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron) to view the TensorFlow file. It makes the graph much easier to understand.

Comment: @Matthihs Hollemans I installed Netron and opened my .pb file with it. I found out that my input name should be "inputs" but I am still struggling to find the output name. Is there something I should be looking for? I give it my best guess based on the netron chart ("detector/yolo-v3/detections") but I got this error: `ValueError: output name: detector/yolo-v3/detections, was provided, but the Tensorflow graph does not contain a tensor with this name.`

Comment: It's usually the thing at the bottom. :-) You may need to add `:0` to the name.